# Onsen-UI: how to update the ons-screen page attribute and reload the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, onsen-ui

I've just started using Onsen UI by implementing the [bootstrap example](http://onsenui.io/guide/bootstrap.html) and I've been trying to get the view to update when I change the page attribute.

```
<body ng-controller="PageLoadingCtrl">
<ons-screen page="{{loadedPage}}"></ons-screen>
</body>
```

My controller's code:

```
app.controller('PageLoadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'notificationService',
    function($scope, $timeout, sharedService){
        $scope.loadedPage = "index.html";
        $scope.updatePage =  function(page){
            $timeout( function (){
                $scope.loadedPage = page;
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 500);
        };
        $scope.$on('changePage', function (event, message){
            $scope.updatePage(message);
        });
    }
]);
```

As you can see I'm using a controller on the body object so that I can update the loadedPage variable however, when I fire the changePage event, the view doesn't change.
After checking the DOM elements with web inspector I can see that page attribute is equal to whatever I pass to the updatePage function.

So far I tried to force a refresh with $apply and $digest but that still doesn't do the trick.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ons-screen need to maintain page stack. it's not intuitive to use binding for the page attribute.

Using ons.screen.presentPage()/dismissPage()/resetPage() is the preferred way.